# mutual friends between two users

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

`friends` table:
[image]

`users` table:
[image]

and want to get name(nom) of mutual friends of two users. i.e:
1 is friend with 2; and 3 is friend with 1 and 2.

users 1 and 2 have mutual friends 3. I want to get his name 'sammy' in one query.

How do I do that?

Comment: Your question is not ready to be posted in my opinion.  If you haven't even tried a query yet, you should at least show us sample data for both tables.  Don't give links; paste actual data into your question, indented by 4 or more spaces to mark it as code.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the logic for `date_confirmation` checking, you have `f1_id` and `f2_id`

```
SELECT f.id_des, u.nom
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id=f.id_des
WHERE 
f.id_exp=$f2_id AND
f.id_des IN (
   SELECT id_des
   FROM friends
   WHERE id_exp=$f1_id
)
```

This only checks **ONE** direction. Where the both invited the same friend. The more complex part is having the other friend inviting one of them (circular invites!)

---

For a full circular answer, there are 4 conditions. You'd need to do a `UNION` between each of these.

1. Both invited the same person (the example I gave)
2. Both invited BY the same person
3. F1 invited by who F2 invited
4. F2 invited by who F1 invited

All the query are IDENTICAL to the one above, except you play with `id_exp` and `id_des` and `$f1_id` and `$f2_id`

Here's the second:

```
SELECT f.id_des, u.nom
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id=f.id_des
WHERE 
f.id_exp=$f2_id AND
f.id_des IN (
   SELECT id_des
   FROM friends
   WHERE id_exp=$f1_id
)
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT f.id_des, u.nom
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id=f.id_des
WHERE 
f.id_des=$f2_id AND
f.id_exp IN (
   SELECT id_exp
   FROM friends
   WHERE id_des=$f1_id
)
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT f.id_des, u.nom
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id=f.id_des
WHERE 
f.id_des=$f2_id AND
f.id_des IN (
   SELECT id_des
   FROM friends
   WHERE id_exp=$f1_id
)
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT f.id_des, u.nom
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id=f.id_des
WHERE 
f.id_exp=$f2_id AND
f.id_des IN (
   SELECT id_des
   FROM friends
   WHERE id_des=$f1_id
)
```

Not easy to test, but that's the concept. Then you have to eliminate duplicates :-)

Comment: Can I have that TWO directions ? I want the "circular invites". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code:

`SELECT f.id_des, u.nom
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id=f.id_des
WHERE 
f.id_exp=445 AND
f.id_des IN (
   SELECT id_des
   FROM friends
   WHERE id_exp=400
)
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT f.id_des, u.nom
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id=f.id_des
WHERE 
f.id_des=445 AND
f.id_exp IN (
   SELECT id_exp
   FROM friends
   WHERE id_des=400
)
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT f.id_des, u.nom
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id=f.id_des
WHERE 
f.id_des=445 AND
f.id_des IN (
   SELECT id_des
   FROM friends
   WHERE id_exp=400
)
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT f.id_des, u.nom
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id=f.id_des
WHERE 
f.id_exp=445 AND
f.id_des IN (
   SELECT id_des
   FROM friends
   WHERE id_des=400
)`

He gives me this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKcVz.png)
This is ma table friends:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkjka.png)
Look at the last three rows of the friends table.

When I swap the position of the two numbers, it gives me another result.
I think the code is not correct.
What do you think?
Thanks.